# Trying to make a script using a macro - code too long

Tags: google-sheets

First of all I must say that my level of knowledge of Google App Scripts is almost nil. I tried to create a script using the macro utility, but the resulting code is too long. I will be very grateful if someone can help me simplify this code. I indicate below the parameters of the subject:

- I have approximately 50 tabs (sheets) in a spreadsheet, although they can be more. (For short, [the spreadsheet that is attached](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IqYXehGiU8A0Td_-7KpZIJNBxRpPWbfq3iIb3G2C_lg) as an example has 5 tabs, whose content, also for short, is the same.)
- Each tab contains data in cells B8:L17 (11 columns and 10 rows of data).
- On a tab called "Index" are the names of the 50 tabs. The names of the tabs must begin in B2. Between one tab name and the next there are 9 empty rows. (All the above I have been able to solve.)

What I want to do --using the "Indirect" formula- is the following:
- That the data of sheet 1 be copied in Index in C2: M11.
- That the data on sheet 2 be copied to Index at C12: M21.
- That the data on sheet 3 be copied to Index in C22: M31.
- That the data of sheet 4 be copied in Index in C32: M41.
- That the data of sheet 5 be copied in Index in C42: M51.
--Etc.

Thank you for your attention.

```
function INDIRECT() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
s.getRange("c2").setFormula('=INDIRECT("\'"&Index!b2&"\'!b8:l17")');
s.getRange("c2").offset(10, 0).activate();
s.getCurrentCell().offset(-10, 0).copyTo(s.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
s.getCurrentCell().offset(10, 0).activate();
s.getCurrentCell().offset(-20, 0).copyTo(s.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
s.getCurrentCell().offset(10, 0).activate();
s.getCurrentCell().offset(-30, 0).copyTo(s.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
s.getCurrentCell().offset(10, 0).activate();
s.getCurrentCell().offset(-40, 0).copyTo(s.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

Comment: There's already a built-in function called `INDIRECT`. I'm pretty sure that it would be a reserved word; you might want to change the name of the script function to something else.

Comment: Here's the [Google reference on naming of functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#naming). Amongst others "The name of a custom function must be distinct from the names of built-in functions".

Comment: You are absolutely right, I am sorry. I have already changed the name of the function in my spreadsheet by the typical name ("myFunction"). You can take a look at the code produced by the macro and tell me if there is any way to abbreviate it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP needs to populate a master sheet with the contents of other sheets.

The following code assumes that the names of the sheets are already populated in Column B (as per the OP spreadsheet).

The equivalent `query` formula (in Cell C3, for example) looks like this:
 `=query(Funda!$B$8:$L$17;" Select * ")`.

This code does not produce a custom formula. It is a routine that might be run only once, looping through Column B of the Master sheet, and inserting the appropriate query into Column C, based on the sheet names listed in Column B. The code might be run only once. Unless there is a change in the spreadsheet layout, or more sheets are added, the query formulas inserted by the code will update the master sheet for all changes on sub-sheets.

```
function so54463600() {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mastername = "Master"; // Change this sheet name to whatever you want
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mastername);

  // The sheet data range
  var datarange = "$B$8:$L$17";

  // set the data and number of sheets in Column B
  var Bvals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var Blast = Bvals.filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row = "+lastRow);//DEBUG

  // loop through the rows of column B
  for (var x = 0; x < lastRow; x++) {

    // action if the cell has contents
    if (Bvals[x][0].length != 0) {

      // Logger.log("DEBUG: x = "+x+", Value = "+Bvals[x][0]+", length: "+Bvals[x][0].length);//DEBUG

      // sample query: =query(Funda!$B$8:$L$17;" Select * ")
      var formula = "=query(" + Bvals[x][0] + "!" + datarange + ";" + '"' + " Select * " + '")';
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the formula is "+formula);//DEBUG

      // Location to set query formula
      Logger.log("target range:" + sheet.getRange(x + 1, 3).getA1Notation());

      // set the formula
      sheet.getRange(x + 1, 3).setFormula(formula);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**REVISION 4 Feb 2019**
Update Sheet Names Programmatically

The number of sheets in a spreadsheet can be 50 or more. Sheet names can change, sheets can be added or deleted. Therefore, in order to ensure that the data shown on the master sheet is complete and accurate, it is desirable that sheet names be inserted programmatically, rather than manually.

This revision includes a new subroutine `buildsheetnames` AND some changes to the original code. Regard this is a complete substitution rather than a simple add-on.

**Sourcing sheet names**
The sheet names are obtained first with `getSheets()`, and then `getName()`.
The user organises the sheets in the screen order that suits them; only sheets listed to the right of the "Master" sheet will be included in the names displayed by the routine.

A user defined variable `startingsheetNumber` is included to define the first sheet to be displayed on the "Master" list. This is obtained by counting ALL the sheets from left to right, beginning the count at zero. The count value of the first sheet to the right of "Master" should be assigned to this variable. The rest of the sheets to the right of "Master" will be automatically included.

```
function so54463600mk2() {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mastername = "Master";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mastername);

  // The sheet data range
  var datarange = "$B$8:$L$17";

  // select the existing sheet data and clear the contents
  // do this in case a sheet is added or deleted; minimize chance of not detecting an error.
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  //Logger.log("last row = "+lastRow+", last Column: "+lastColumn);
  var masterrange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow - 1, lastColumn - 1);
  masterrange.clear();


  // update the sheet names in column B
  // run the sub-routine buildsheetnames
  buildsheetnames(mastername);


  // set the data and number of sheets in Column B
  var Bvals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var Blast = Bvals.filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row = "+lastRow);//DEBUG

  // loop through the rows of column B
  for (var x = 0; x < lastRow; x++) {

    // action if the cell has contents
    if (Bvals[x][0].length != 0) {

      // Logger.log("DEBUG: x = "+x+", Value = "+Bvals[x][0]+", length: "+Bvals[x][0].length);//DEBUG

      // sample query: =query(Funda!$B$8:$L$17;" Select * ")
      //var formula = "=query(" + Bvals[x][0] + "!"+datarange+";"+'"'+" Select * "+'")';
      var formula = "=query(" + "'" + Bvals[x][0] + "'!" + datarange + ";" + '"' + " Select * " + '")';
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the formula is "+formula);//DEBUG

      // Location to set query formula
      Logger.log("target range:" + sheet.getRange(x + 1, 3).getA1Notation());

      // set the formula
      sheet.getRange(x + 1, 3).setFormula(formula);
    }
  }
}

function buildsheetnames(mastername) {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(mastername);

  // move the curcor to cell B2
  var row = 2;
  var column = 2;
  sheet.getRange(2, 2).activate();

  // get the list of sheets
  var sheetlist = ss.getSheets();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of sheets: "+sheetlist.length);//DEBUG

  // Displaying Sheet names on the master sheet
  // Instructions:
  // 1 - View the spreadsheet with sheets laid out at the bottom of the screen
  // 2 - Move the sheets into the order that you want; 
  // 2a - Sheets to the left of "Master" (or whatever sheet you define as "mastername") wouldn't be included in the sheet names written onto Master
  // 2b - Only the names of those sheets to the right of "Master" will be displayed.
  // 3 - Count ALL the sheets, from left to right of screen. The first sheet will be zero, the second sheet will be one, and so on. 
  // 4 - Stop when you reach the first sheet that you want the name displayed on Master
  // 5 - Update the count value for that sheet to the variable 'startingsheetNumber'.
  // 6 - Note: the variable "sheetrowseparation" is the number of rows between each name; 
  // 6a - This is the same as the number of data rows on each data sheet. 
  // 6b - If the number of data rows ever changes, then you can change this variable.
  var startingsheetNumber = 6;
  var sheetrowseparation = 10;

  // loop through the sheets
  if (sheetlist.length > 1) {

    for (var i = startingsheetNumber; i < sheetlist.length; i++) {
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: Sheet#: "+i+", Sheet name: "+sheetlist[i].getName());//DEBUG
      sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(sheetlist[i].getName());
      row = row + sheetrowseparation;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Cool! That is exactly what I wanted. The script works perfectly. I am very grateful.

Comment: So sorry. I forgot to comment that the names of the sheets can contain more than one word. When this happens an error occurs, as you can see in my [spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IqYXehGiU8A0Td_-7KpZIJNBxRpPWbfq3iIb3G2C_lg). Would you mind correcting your script to keep in mind that the names of the sheets can have more than one word? Thanks again.

Comment: Is the order of the sheets important? It is possible to get the sheet names from the system; possibly this is more efficient that having you enter the sheet names beforehand-though I guess you probably have done that already.

Comment: Yes, the order of the sheets is (very) important ... and no, I have not yet generated the final sheets. It would be very useful to be able to generate the sheets from the system, as you say. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: To copy with sheets that have a space in their name, change "var formula as follows". `var formula = "=query("+"'" + Bvals[x][0] + "'!"+datarange+";"+'"'+" Select * "+'")';`

Comment: Hi Tedinoz. As expected, now everything works perfectly. As expected, now everything works perfectly. (Earlier also, but it was my fault I did not warn you that the sheet names could have more than 1 word.) Thanks again.

Comment: I have added a revision that includes inserting the sheet names programmatically, rather than manually. Note#1: this is not an add-on; there are changes in the core code too - so take ALL the code, not just the sub-routine. Note#2, read the notes about assigning a value to the variable `startingsheetNumber`. You need to do this to reflect your live data scenario.

Comment: Wow! Here there are a lot of work hours. I do not know how to thank you for the effort. I am trying to put into practice your new code, which replaces the old one. I'll tell you how it went. Thanks again.

Comment: You are very welcome. I deliberately left a lot of `Logger` statements so that you could debug and/or understand the effect of an element of code. The code is not perfect but I  hope that it is something that you can learn from, and use to enhance your own skills.

Comment: It took me a while to understand the new subroutine "buildsheetnames" but in the end everything is now clear and everything works perfectly. Your solutions have also helped me get into this fascinating world of scripts. So much so that I am now trying to figure out how to hide the last empty rows of a sheet. I found some scripts that work, but they hide the rows one by one, in place of all at once, so the "hide" time is too long when there are many rows. I am very grateful for the help you have given me. Thanx.